# VS2010: "Unable to find the requested .NET Framework Data Provider"

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-ce

In VS2010, when I add an SQL Compact database to my App_Data folder, I'm unable to open and edit its schema. When I double click it says "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider"

I installed SQL compact using [NuGet's SQL compact repo](http://nuget.org/packages/SqlServerCompact) and I've also installed "Microsoft SQL Server Data tools, Data Projects" using Microsoft Web Platform Installer 3.0.

What do I have to do so I can modify the schema of the SQL Compact database in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

I used Windows Update that involved upgrading SQL Server 2008 to service pack 3 and that seem to work.